# Grouping in data.table: how to get more than 1 column of results?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object like this one

```
library(data.table)

a <- structure(list(PERMNO = c(10006L, 10006L, 10015L, 10015L, 20000L, 20000L), 
                    SHROUT = c(1427L, 1427L, 1000L, 1001L, 200L, 200L), 
                    PRC = c(6.5, 6.125, 0.75, 0.5, 3, 4), 
                    RET = c(0.005, -0.005, -0.001, 0.05, -0.002, 0.0031)),
                   .Names = c("PERMNO", "SHROUT", "PRC", "RET"), 
               class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

setkey(a,PERMNO)
```

and I need to perform a number of calculations by `PERMNO`, but here in this example let's supposed they are only 2:

```
mktcap <- a[ , tail(SHROUT,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),by=PERMNO]
sqret <- a[, sum(RET^2),by=PERMNO]
```

which produce

```
> mktcap
     PERMNO       V1
[1,]  10006 8740.375
[2,]  10015  500.500
[3,]  20000  800.000

> sqret
     PERMNO        V1
[1,]  10006 5.000e-05
[2,]  10015 2.501e-03
[3,]  20000 1.361e-05
```

I would like to combine the two functions into one, to produce a matrix (or data.table, data.frame, whatever) with 3 columns, the first with the `PERMNO`s, the second with `mktcap` and the third with `sqrt`.

The problem is that this grouping function (i.e. `variable[ , function(), by= ]`) seems to only produce results with two columns, one with the keys and one with results.

This is my attempt (one of many) to produce what I want:

```
comb.fun <- function(datai) {
     mktcap <- as.matrix(tail(datai[,1],n=1)*tail(datai[,2],n=1),ncol=1)
     sqret <- as.matrix(sum(datai[,3]^2),ncol=1)
     return(c(mktcap,sqret))
}   

myresults <- a[, comb.fun(cbind(SHROUT,PRC,RET)), by=PERMNO]
```

which produces

```
     PERMNO           V1
[1,]  10006 8.740375e+03
[2,]  10006 5.000000e-05
[3,]  10015 5.005000e+02
[4,]  10015 2.501000e-03
[5,]  20000 8.000000e+02
[6,]  20000 1.361000e-05
```

(the results are all there, but they were forced into one column). No matter what I try, I cannot get grouping to return a matrix with more than two columns (or more than one column of results).

Is it possible to get two or more column of results with grouping in `data.table`?

Comment: +1 for the nicely reproducible example, and for eliciting such a clear explanation of 'macro expressions' from Matthew Dowle. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (using `list()` to collect the several desired summary stats) is there in the excellent Examples section of the `?data.table` help file. (It's about 20 lines up from the bottom).

```
out <- a[ , list(mktcap = tail(SHROUT,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),
                 sqret  = sum(RET^2)),
         by=PERMNO]

out
#    PERMNO   mktcap     sqret
# 1:  10006 8740.375 5.000e-05
# 2:  10015  500.500 2.501e-03
# 3:  20000  800.000 1.361e-05
```

---

**Edit:**

In the comments below, Matthew Dowle describes a simple way to clean up code in which the `j` argument in calls like `x[i,j,by]` is getting awkwardly long.

Implementing his suggestion on the call above, you could instead do:

```
## 1) Use quote() to make an expression object out of the statement passed to j
mm <- quote(list(mktcap = tail(SHROUT,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),
                 sqret  = sum(RET^2)))

## 2) Use eval() to evaluate it as if it had been typed directly in the call
a[ , eval(mm), by=PERMNO]
#    PERMNO   mktcap     sqret
# 1:  10006 8740.375 5.000e-05
# 2:  10015  500.500 2.501e-03
# 3:  20000  800.000 1.361e-05
```

Comment: that's great, but can I have list(function())? I ask that because the example I gave is a very simplified version of what I need to do. I would like to have a function which returns 5 results, and the calculations are not one-line calculations like the ones I provided...

Comment: You mean something like `a[,{r <- range(PRC); list(min=r[1], max=2[2])}, by=PERMNO]` or `a[,{setNames(as.list(range(PRC)), c("min", "max"))}, by=PERMNO]`?

Comment: Ha! I adapted your answer and have `out <- a[ ,list(mkk = mktcap(SHROUT,PRC), sqret = sum(RET^2)), by=PERMNO]` where `mktcap` is a function. I was happy with that, but I think your comment will also be useful (I am new in R). Hey, thanks heaps!

Comment: @Vivi Just to mention another construct as a further option. Instead of `j=myfunction()` (which won't work without laboriously passing in all the arguments) you create an _expression_ (using `quote()` instead of `function()`). It's a bit like a _macro_. Then it's `j=eval(mymacro)` instead of `j=myfunction()`. See FAQ 1.6 for detailed example. This can be more efficient than a function call, and convenient. When `data.table` sees `j=eval(mymacro)` it knows to find `mymacro` in calling scope so not to be tripped up if a column name happens to be called `mymacro`, too.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- That's a nice explanation. For me, it came across much more effectively than FAQ 1.6, which I've read again and again without ever fully grasping.  I think making the parallel with functions (which is what we naturally reach for in this situation) really helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh That's also one way to run the same `j` for a bunch of different `by`. Will add examples of that into 1.6 too.

Comment: @MatthewDowle For some reason I thought the reference manual was the only document for data.table. I will read the FAQ now: the first question already caught my attention! Very pertinent when you start using `data.table`!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks for adding the example for Matthew's comment, it was really helpful.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien just to let you know, with your help I managed to get the results I wanted using a grouping inside a grouping, and `quote()`: `results62 <- data62nona[,.SD[,{setkey=PERMNO; eval(mm)},by=PERMNO],by=TM]`  :)

Comment: FAQ 1.6 now embellished, [#517](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/517)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
comb.fun <- function(a) {
 mktcap <- a[ , tail(SHROUT,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),by=PERMNO]
 sqret <- a[, sum(RET^2),by=PERMNO]

 return(merge(mktcap,sqret))
}
```

Comment: My issue is that I have a grouping inside a grouping. Your case works, but when it goes to the grouping in the level above, it would transform into 2 columns again...

Comment: And, one `by` query is much more efficient than two `by` query.

Comment: Cool. The final few minor bugs are proving tricky to iron out, but hopefully 1.8.1 should be on CRAN soon...

Comment: @ttmaccer Reading back my question, I agree it wasn't very clear what I was asking. To be honest, I am not sure what I wanted will work with my nested grouping either, but that's what I was trying to do. I didn't know about merge (I always use cbind, rbind or c), so cheers for that.