# data.table vs plyr regression output

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table package is very helpful in terms of speed.  But I am having trouble actually using the output from a linear regression.  Is there an easy way to get the data.table output to be as pretty/useful as that from the plyr package?  Below is an example.  Thank you!

```
library('data.table');
library('plyr');

REG <- data.table(ID=c(rep('Frank',5),rep('Tony',5),rep('Ed',5)), y=rnorm(15), x=rnorm(15), z=rnorm(15));
REG;

ddply(REG, .(ID), function(x) coef(lm(y ~ x + z, data=x)));

REG[, coef(lm(y ~ x + z)), by=ID];
```

The data.table coefficient estimates are output in a single column whereas the plyr/ddply coefficient estimates are output in multiple and nicely labeled columns.

I know I can run the regression three times with data.table but that seems really inefficient.  I could be wrong, though.

```
REG[, Intercept=coef(lm(y ~ x + z))[1],
      x        =coef(lm(y ~ x + z))[2],
      z        =coef(lm(y ~ x + z))[3], by=ID];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
> REG[, as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x + z))), by=ID];
        ID (Intercept)           x         z
[1,] Frank  -0.2928611  0.07215896  1.835106
[2,]  Tony   0.9120795 -1.11153056  2.041260
[3,]    Ed   1.0498359  5.77131778 -1.253741
```

I have the nagging feeling that this question was asked less than a week ago, but I don't think I arrived at this approach when I tried it and I don't remember than any answer was this compact.

Oh, there it is .. on r-help. Matthew can comment on the rightfulness of this if he wants. I guess the message is that functions returning lists will not have dimensions dropped. The interesting thing was the using `list(coef(lm(...))` did not succeed in the manner we hoped.

Comment: There was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233183/grouping-in-data-table-how-to-get-more-than-1-column-of-results/11233262#11233262) from yesterday (see esp. the second comment to my answer) but it's nice to have this demo'd more prominently.

Comment: And notice that `list()` is not the answer.

Comment: That's why I referenced the comment ;) (Just trying to show from you where you might have gotten that nagging feeling.)

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem with `list()` is that it returns a *one-element list* containing a length-three vector, rather than a *three-element list*, each element of which is a length-one vector (which is what we need if we want data.table to put the results in three different columns).