# Regression and summary statistics by group within a data.table

Tags: r, list, grouping, data.table, regression

I would like to calculate some summary statistics and perform different regressions by group within a data table, and have the results in "wide" format (i.e. one row per group with several columns).  I can do it in multiple steps, but it seems like it should be possible to do all at once.

Consider this **example data**:

```
set.seed=46984
dt <- data.table(ID=c(rep('Frank',5),rep('Tony',5),rep('Ed',5)), y=rnorm(15), x=rnorm(15), z=rnorm(15),key="ID")
dt
#       ID          y          x            z
# 1:    Ed  0.2129400 -0.3024061  0.845335632
# 2:    Ed  0.4850342 -0.5159197 -0.087965415
# 3:    Ed  1.8917489  1.7803220  0.760465271
# 4:    Ed -0.4330460 -2.1720944  0.973812545
# 5:    Ed  0.7685060  0.7947470  1.279761200
# 6: Frank  0.4978475 -0.2906851  0.568101004
# 7: Frank  0.6323386 -0.5596599  1.537133025
# 8: Frank -0.8243218 -0.4354885  0.057818033
# 9: Frank  1.2402488  0.3229422  0.005995249
#10: Frank  0.2436210 -0.2651422  0.349532173
#11:  Tony  0.4179568  0.1418463  0.142380549
#12:  Tony  0.7036613  0.4402572  0.141237901
#13:  Tony -0.1978720 -0.9553784  0.480425820
#14:  Tony -1.7269375 -0.1881292  0.370583351
#15:  Tony  1.1064903  0.4375014 -0.798221750
```

Let's say I want to get the median by ID, perform linear regression on y ~ x by ID, and perform linear regression on y ~ x + z by ID.  Here I get the median:

```
dt.med <- dt[,list(y.med=median(y)),by=ID]
dt.med
#      ID     y.med
#1:    Ed 0.4850342
#2: Frank 0.4978475
#3:  Tony 0.4179568
```

And thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267149/1344789) by @DWin, here I get the two individual sets of regression coefficients as columns by ID:

```
dt.reg.1 <- dt[,as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x))), by=ID]
dt.reg.1
#      ID (Intercept)         x
#1:    Ed  0.63057884 0.5482373
#2: Frank  0.69720351 1.3813007
#3:  Tony  0.08588421 1.0179131

dt.reg.2 <- dt[,as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x + z))), by=ID]
dt.reg.2
#      ID (Intercept)         x          z
#1:    Ed   0.8262577 0.5587170 -0.2582699
#2: Frank   0.4317538 2.7221024  1.1807442
#3:  Tony   0.1494439 0.3166547 -1.2029693
```

Now I have to join the three result sets, and rename the columns:

```
dt.ans <- dt.med[dt.reg.1][dt.reg.2]
setnames(dt.ans,c("ID","y.med","reg.1.c0","reg.1.c1","reg.2.c0","reg.2.c1","reg.2.c2"))
```

Finally, here is the **desired output** for the example:

```
dt.ans
#      ID     y.med   reg.1.c0  reg.1.c1  reg.2.c0  reg.2.c1   reg.2.c2
#1:    Ed 0.4850342 0.63057884 0.5482373 0.8262577 0.5587170 -0.2582699
#2: Frank 0.4978475 0.69720351 1.3813007 0.4317538 2.7221024  1.1807442
#3:  Tony 0.4179568 0.08588421 1.0179131 0.1494439 0.3166547 -1.2029693
```

It seems inefficient to calculate the three results, join them, and then rename the columns.  Also, my actual tables are largish so I'd like to make sure I don't use too much system memory.  **Is it possible to do this all within "one" data.table statement?**  Or more generally, can this be done more efficiently?

I've tried different things.  Here is one failed example that gives the median but ignores the regression coefficients:

```
dt[,as.list(median(y),coef(lm(y ~ x))), by=ID]
#      ID        V1
#1:    Ed 0.4850342
#2: Frank 0.4978475
#3:  Tony 0.4179568
```

Comment: you have a typo - should have `set.seed(#)` instead of `set.seed=#` (and that will change all of the numbers you have)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
dt[,c(y.med = median(y),
      reg.1 = as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x))),
      reg.2 = as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x + z)))), by=ID]
#      ID     y.med reg.1.(Intercept)   reg.1.x reg.2.(Intercept)      reg.2.x   reg.2.z
#1:    Ed 0.7280448        0.75977555 0.1132509        0.83322290 -0.484348116 0.7655563
#2: Frank 0.6100339       -0.07830664 0.2700846        0.04720686  0.004027939 0.7168521
#3:  Tony 0.2710623       -0.78319379 0.9166601       -0.35836990  0.622822617 0.4161102
```

Comment: Yeah, that's as simple as I thought it should be, but struggled to find on my own.  Thanks for the near instantaneous response!  Is there a way to rename the coefficient columns directly, or does that require a secondary step (as in my example)?

Comment: @dnlbrky the columns are generated by `coef(lm` so easiest thing to do is just rename them after (maybe using a regex or two)

Comment: how would you adjust this for a polynomial (cubic) regression so that coefs are listed for all 3 terms per ID?