# Use Predict on data.table with Linear Regression

Tags: r, data.table, lm, predict

Regrad to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266930/data-table-vs-plyr-regression-output?rq=1), I have created an example to play with linear regression on **data.table** package as follows:

```
## rm(list=ls()) # anti-social
library(data.table)
set.seed(1011)
DT = data.table(group=c("b","b","b","a","a","a"),
                v1=rnorm(6),v2=rnorm(6), y=rnorm(6))
setkey(DT, group)
ans <- DT[,as.list(coef(lm(y~v1+v2))), by = group]
```

return,

```
   group (Intercept)        v1        v2
1:     a    1.374942 -2.151953 -1.355995
2:     b   -2.292529  3.029726 -9.894993
```

I am able to obtain the coefficients of the `lm` function.

**My question is:**
How can we directly use `predict` to new observations ?  If we have the new observations as follows:

```
new <- data.table(group=c("b","b","b","a","a","a"),v1=rnorm(6),v2=rnorm(6))
```

I have tried:

```
setkey(new, group)
DT[,predict(lm(y~v1+v2), new), by = group]
```

but it returns me strange answers:

```
    group         V1
 1:     a  -2.525502
 2:     a   3.319445
 3:     a   4.340253
 4:     a   3.512047
 5:     a   2.928245
 6:     a   1.368679
 7:     b  -1.835744
 8:     b  -3.465325
 9:     b  19.984160
10:     b -14.588933
11:     b  11.280766
12:     b  -1.132324
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are predicting onto the entire `new` data set each time. If you want to predict only on the new data for each group you need to subset the "newdata" by group.

This is an instance where `.BY` will be useful. Here are two possibilities

```
a <- DT[,predict(lm(y ~ v1 + v2), new[.BY]), by = group]

b <- new[,predict(lm(y ~ v1 + v2, data = DT[.BY]), newdata=.SD),by = group]
```

both of which give identical results

```
identical(a,b)
# [1] TRUE
a
#   group         V1
#1:     a  -2.525502
#2:     a   3.319445
#3:     a   4.340253
#4:     b -14.588933
#5:     b  11.280766
#6:     b  -1.132324
```

Comment: Nice. I knew that was the problem, I just couldn't sort out how to fix it. `.BY` is a new one for me.

Comment: @thelatemail - this is the first time I've managed to find a use for `.BY`

Comment: @mnel I'm new to data.table. I have read the .BY, but still don't get how it works.  Could you explain ?

Comment: @newbie `.BY` is described in the help for `data.table` (`?data.table`). `.BY` is a list containing the values of the by variables. This means it can be used to join with other keyed data.tables to select the rows which match the current `BY` grouping.

Comment: Andrew Brooks wrote [a great article](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#calculate-a-function-over-a-group-using-by-excluding-each-entity-in-a-second-category) on data.table special symbols' usage, including .BY. It's a good read for those wanting to understand those methods better.